# fatal error LNK1112 when nuitka compile python

Tags: python, visual-studio, compiler-errors, architecture, nuitka

When I was compiling my python project using Nuitka, there came an error: 

`python36.lib(python36.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'`

I am using `Windows 10 64bit`, `Nuitka 0.5.28.1 Python3.6 64 bit`, `Visual Studio 2017 Community` and `Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)|`.

**I want to build a `x64` exe file.**

I've searched Internet saying that something `Configuration Properties`, `Target Machine`. However, **I don't have an VS project when using Nuitka**, so I don't know where to config.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem today.

I think it is because anaconda is probably compiled with a different C compiler. I just used the normal python (no anaconda) and pipenv to have environments.